# Answer to my question disappeared

Tags: support, deleted-answers

An answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190862/r-source-personal-scripts-keeping-some-functions-hidden) of mine has disappeared.

I really don't understand why. It was the solution to the problem and I was going to accept it. I got a red message of a technical problem (kind of) and, after refreshing the page, the answer was gone.

Probably a mod in between time deleted it, but why?

Now I could easily close the question answering myself, but I feel this as highly unethical.

Comment: Maybe the answerer deleted it himself?not necessarily a mod

Comment: I thought that if you edited a post the deletion/modification remained visible.

Comment: Edits are different from deletions. Only users with moderation privileges (10k+) can see deleted posts. Do keep in mind that users delete posts for a reason...

Comment: @CodyGray: thanks, in fact I tried to contact the poster to learn about his/her possible extra findings, Hopefully s/he will comment on my solution  where of course I give credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was deleted by the author. The content of the answer (originally posted by [Alexander Griffith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6141186/alexander-griffith)) is as follows:

> `g` still exists, it is in `<environment: foo_>` which is still the parent of `<environment: foo>`. If you want to access it use `get("g",env=environment(f))`. `get` will search through the parent of the environment, not just those in the search path.
>
> Making `g` available to all functions in `<environment: foo>` and not the `global` env is a harder problem.

If you believe that this is the correct solution, you can answer your question by yourself, but you should probably credit the original author.

Comment: Side note: one common reason to delete own answer is finding hard to fix problem with it... Make sure to carefully review/think about that answer before copy-pasting deleted answer as solution.

Comment: "The answer was deleted by the author", presumably for a good reason. Reposting it here doesn't make much sense to me. The reason 10k users can see deleted content is for moderation purposes, not so they can repost it on Meta without the author's consent. If you think it shouldn't have been deleted, you can cast a vote to undelete it.

Comment: `you should probably credit the original author`  You're violating the law if you *don't* credit the author.  Big difference.

Comment: @Servy Millions of programmers are violating the law when they copy-paste code from Stack Overflow without attribution.

Comment: @CodyGray Where does SE ToS or at least some Meta post say that I shouldn't repost deleted content without author's consent?

Comment: @Gothdo The content is licences under CC Wiki licence.  You're only allowed to use the work if you provide attribution.  If you don't it's a violation of copyright.

Comment: If the author chose to delete it, you should respect the author's wishes and not repost it.

Comment: I thought about adding in a clarification that I wasn't saying you were violating the law or some license by doing this, but I figured it went without saying. Plus, the comment would have been too long. Anyhoo, no, you're probably entirely within your rights to do this, or I would have edited it back out. But that doesn't mean it is something you *should* do. The spirit of the law and so on. Consider that the person made a massive error and feels having his name attached to it makes him look perpetually like an idiot. This is why he has the right to delete it. You're making that difficult.